# TestCafe using client Functions to get data from a HTML dataTable

Tags: javascript, arrays, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

I am trying to **scrape** data from a bricklet in the UI(i.e. HTML dataTable) and using a testCafe client function to do this but I haven't been successful. I have a few questions about my code and would like someone to point me in the right direction.

I first put my client function in the test file(test.js) which houses all my other test cases and called the function from one of my tests. Just like this example here: - https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/examples-of-using-client-functions.html   check section "**complex DOM queries**"   but testCafe gets stuck, the browser closes but the execution is stuck

Here is my client function. It is in my file that houses all my tests - test.js

```
fixture`Getting Started`
    .page`${config.baseUrl}`;

    const getTableRowValues = ClientFunction(() => {
        console.log("inside client function");
        const elements = document.querySelector('#bricklet_summary_studtable > tbody').querySelectorAll('tr td');
        const array = [];
        console.log(elements.length); 
        for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
            console.log("inside for");
            const customerName  = elements[i].textContent; 
                array.push(customerName);
        }
        return array;
 });
```

Here is my test case:

```
test('My 4th test - Check the bricklet data matches the expected data', async t => {
    await t.navigateTo('https://myurl.com/app/home/students');
    await page_studTest.click_studentlink();
    await t
        .expect(await page_studTest.exists_ListPageHeader()).ok('do something async', { allowUnawaitedPromise: true })//check the compare button does not exists
    await t        .navigateTo('https://myurl.com/app/home/students/application/stud/id/details/test.html')
    await t
        .expect(await page_studTest.getText_studHeader(t)).eql('student123',
            "the header text does not match");
    let arr = await getTableRowValues();
    await console.log(arr);        
});
```

I thought this will get the values from the UI in an array and I will compare it to another array of test values that I will hard code later.

At first, I tried client functions in my page class(page object model: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/use-page-model.html) and I put the client function in the constructor and called it from a async function in same page class and called the async function from my test.js. All my tests are structured this way but this only prints the following in the console

```
Valuesfunction __$$clientFunction$$() {
            const testRun = builder._getTestRun();
            const callsite = (0, _getCallsite.getCallsiteForMethod)(builder.callsiteNames.execution);
            const args = [];

            // OPTIMIZATION: don't leak `arguments` object.
            for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) args.push(arguments[i]);

            return builder._executeCommand(args, testRun, callsite);
        }
```

which is not useful to debug the problem.

There are no examples on testCafe site as to how/where to put the client function when you use the page-object model. Could someone, please share some insight? I am interested in knowing the best way to structure my tests.

Comment: I tried adding a testCafe sleep to the end of the test case thinking probably the client function needs time to execute. TestCafe waits for 15 seconds and closes the window after that but the execution is stuck in the console

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any problems in your code which can make TestCafe hang. I didn't find any syntax errors or incorrect calls to TestCafe methods either. I only wish that you take note that the `await` keyword should not be called before `console.log`. Though this should not lead to any issues.

Probably the use of a custom promise with the [{ allowUnawaitedPromise: true } option](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/expect/ok.html#optionsallowunawaitedpromise) can lead to problems, however it's difficult to determine it without the full project.

I recommend you prepare a simple project with a sample test file to demonstrate the issue and create a separate bug report in the TestCafe repository using the following  [form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this one and other Qs regarding testCafe. appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I tried to return a promise from my client function and then it worked.

```
const getTableRowValues = ClientFunction(() => {
    const array = [];
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#bricklet_summary_studtable > tbody > tr > *');
        elements.forEach(function (element, i) {
            let text = element.textContent;
            array[i] = text.trim();
        });
        resolve(array);
    });
});
```

I resolve a single dimensional array as the assertion wasn't working with a 2D array in the test when I compare the result of the client function to a 2D expected value.However this serves the purpose for now.

Comment: I find this as the most challenging part with most of the javascript frameworks out there( protractor etc). The async behavior of javascript and how to wrap page objects, helper functions( client functions in test cafe) into a promise and structure a code in such a way that the browser object doesn't run ahead of test execution. TestCafe is awesome as it waits for page transitions and assertions. However when complex tests are wirtten, there will be many service calls and DB calls and in depth knowledge of promises/callback is important